# JDBC with Oracle DB - Using parameter marker with like condition

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

In *JDBC* with *Oracle DB*, I want to retrieve Employees whose first name starts with a specific letter. How can I use parameter marker "?" in a like condition?  `setXXX()` method doesn't see it when i place it  in a single quotation.

ex:

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
String sql="SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE FIRST_NAME like '?%'";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, firstName);
```

Comment: Finally found [a possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43051975/266304) but there must be a better one, that show's rzwitserloot's approach too....

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate the bound value with the wildcard:

```
"SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE FIRST_NAME like ? || '%'"
```

You could also check the first letter explicitly with something like:

```
"SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME, 1, 1) = ?"
```

but that may be less efficient (unless you add a function-based index).

Answer (score 1):

The normal route is to set the % in the 'setX' call, so your query becomes `SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE FIRST_NAME like ?` and then `.setString(1, firstChar + "%");`

The alternative is as @Alex Poole answered: use `WHERE FIRST_NAME like (? || '%')`

NB: This answer was edited: The query included an erroneous % at the end; it has been removed.

Comment: You shouldn't still have the % in the statement though, right?

Comment: `like ?%` won't work. That `%` must be in a string literal, so `? || '%'` is the only thing that will work.